# jQuery: How to access elements in XML file with a specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am working on a college basketball statistics website for my university internship. I have been tasked with pulling the statistics from an XML document (loaded via Ajax) and displaying them on a website for the media. I have got the basics down and can display individual pieces of data like the venue, date, etc. However, I am having trouble with accessing individual pieces of data with specific attributes. For example.....

```
 <bbgame>
    <team vh="V" id="UOU" name="STATE COLLEGE" record="8-2">
        <linescore line="24,36" score="60">
          <lineprd prd="1" score="24"></lineprd>
          <lineprd prd="2" score="36"></lineprd>
        </linescore>
        <totals>
          <stats fgm="22" fga="58" fgm3="4" fga3="15" ftm="12" fta="20" tp="60" blk="4" stl="5" ast="6" min="203" oreb="10" dreb="20" treb="30" pf="24" tf="0" to="13" deadball="3,1"
                 fgpct="37.9" fg3pct="26.7" ftpct="60.0"></stats>
    </totals>
    </team>
</bbame>
```

There are two such entries in this XML file. One for the home team "H" and one above for the visiting team "V". 
I am trying to write in jQuery / Ajax where I can access the individual pieces for each team separately and then store them in a div. Here is my code sample. I would like to do this for each piece of data for each team and then create a table to store the data. I am just having trouble telling jQuery/Javascript that I only want the 'fgm' field-goals-made, from the Visiting team in this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 $(xml_parse).find('team[vh="v"]').find('totals').find('stats').each(function() {
           $('#fgm').append($(this).attr('fgm'));
           });
```

Comment: Please ignore my XML sample if it is not formatted correctly. I have a working XML that is several pages long and I just took a sample from this for brevity. It is properly formatted and working. I am just having trouble accessing it.

Comment: looks fine to me... what is the problem

Comment: Before I added find('team[vh="v"]') I just have find('team') and it was giving me the fgm for both teams. Is this the proper syntax to find a specific attribute?

Comment: see my answer below... attribute values are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see is the attribute value for `vh` it should be `V` not `v` as attribute selector values are case sensitive

```
$(xml_parse).find('team[vh="V"]').find('totals').find('stats').each(function () {
    $('#fgm').append($(this).attr('fgm'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6GH9d/)

---

Also you can cleanup the code to

```
var $vstats = $(xml_parse).find('team[vh="V"] totals stats');
$('#fgm').append($vstats.attr('fgm'));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nmN8a/)

Comment: Wow. Rookie mistake. I changed the "v" to "V" and it is displaying correctly now. If you have time could I ask how you would go about adding the stats for the "V" team into a table?

Comment: @user3210595 did you mean about database or UI

Comment: Could also make it: 

.find('team[vh=v]')

 -- without quotes, it's case insensitive :)

Comment: UI. I am only tasked with displaying the data. Not storing it. I was interested in for example having a table that stores the visiting team stats. Any help to point me in the right direction would be great. Should I store the individual values in a div and then add them to a table? Or is there a way to format an entire list of attributes, for example in this case the <stats> for the "V" team into a table? Thank you all so much for your help! This website has been a lifesaver.

Comment: @user3210595 the first step is to decide on what the UI should look like and create a mock up table... we can place the correct values later... so first you design a table like `<table>
    <tr>
        <td>FGM</td>
        <td id="fgm"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FGA</td>
        <td id="fga"></td>
    </tr>
</table>` then share it after that we can have a look at it

Comment: @ArunPJohny Okay thank you I am doing that now. I will respond in a few minutes with a sample table. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're right about being case sensitive Arun. After stepping thru in the debugger, I've found normal CSS (in your CSS) selectors are not case-sensitive if you exclude the "", but jQuery/QuerySelectorAll requires the "". Strange.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Updated the fiddle. Please forgive me if I did it wrong. This is the first time I have used jFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jonbritt/nmN8a/2/.  EDIT: Also I'm not sure if this is appropriate for this website but if you have a Gmail account I would love the opportunity to chat with you for a few minutes while I am working through this. Again I appreciate your help so far. This thread has helped me immensely.

Comment: @user3210595 will you have multiple visiting teams in a xml

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm not sure what you mean. I should have stated previously that this file is a sample of a file that is dynamically generated by my university's basketball statistics team. That is why I am loading it via ajax so that members of the sports media can view the file on their computer. In this instance there is only 1 visiting team. There is a different file generated for each game.